# Object or String does not contain definition for Imagebutton

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, imagebutton, imageurl

Im trying to put my ImageButton ID in front of Imageurl. So it places the correct image at the correct button. I've saved the ImageButton ID in my database.

Now my problem;

When Im trying to read it out of the database like this:

```
reader["Appplaats"].ImageUrl = "~/Images/" + reader["Link"] + ".png";
```

I get the error:
'object' does not contain a definition for 'ImageUrl' and no extension method 'ImageUrl' accepting a first argument...

I've tried to write it to a string with: To.String() but it then says:

'string' does not contain a definition for 'ImageUrl' and no extension method 'ImageUrl' accepting a first argument...

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: Cast it to the appropriate control first

Comment: Yes I understand, but how?

Comment: Hmm, looks like I misunderstood your requirement. You should first try to get the control from the page whose name matches your retrieved value. Then cast it appropriately and do the rest.

Comment: Yes so I have to retrieve who is logged in?

Comment: No. Let's say you have an ImageButton with name ib1. If I am right to assume that this is the string you retrieve from the DB, then you should first get the page control which has that name. Here's a link to help you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt340bh4%28v=vs.140%29.aspx